# Trouble installing an R package using R CMD install

Tags: r

I just ran the following command after running `R CMD build pkg` and `R CMD check pkg` and it completed without errors.

> R CMD install -t /home/wdkrnls/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.1  pkg_0.1.0.tar.gz

However, I still can't use it via `library(pkg)` from `R`. Looking in the library directory, all I see is the tarball, no pkg directory. When I try and untar it and then load in R, I get the error:

> Error in library(e2pa) : 'e2pa' is not a valid installed package

Alternatively, when I try to install with

> R CMD install -l /home/wdkrnls/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.1  pkg_0.1.0.tar.gz

It tells me `-l` is an invalid option.

Another failed possibility:

> R CMD install -t /home/wdkrnls/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.1/pkg pkg_0.1.0.tar.gz
>   install: accessing `/home/wdkrnls/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.1/pkg': No such file or directory

What is the right way to install a package into a personal library in R?

Comment: your package isn't named `3.1 pkg` is it?

Comment: no, but I'm using R 3.1, and I replaced the true name of my package with pkg.

Comment: I'm trying to specify the name of the package at the end following `R CMD INSTALL [options] [-l lib] pkgs`

Comment: My package is located in my home directory, because I'm developing it in `~/pkg`.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of R installed?

Comment: @Thomas: nope, but last time I upgraded it made me a new package directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unix commands are case-sensitive and

```
 R CMD install ....
```

as you typed invokes a different `/usr/bin/install` than the R-internal script `INSTALL` which the actually mandated form

```
 R CMD INSTALL ...
```

uses.  See all the relevant docs -- it is always UPPERCASE.

Once you have the correct script, `-l ...` is recognised:

```
edd@max:~$ R CMD INSTALL -l /tmp/demo git/drat_0.0.2.4.tar.gz 
* installing *source* package ‘drat’ ...
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (drat)
edd@max:~$
```

Comment: Thanks! I was following RStudio's otherwise excellent Package Development cheatsheet which shows the command as `R CMD install`.

Comment: That would be a cruel and unusual bug. Can you reach out to them?